# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib, image-compression

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code? I keep on getting a `NoneType` error. I am trying to create a histogram.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\Pictures\naturalScene.bmp',0)
plt.hist(img.ravel(),256,[0,256]);
plt.show()
```

Comment: img is just empty(None) . check the path again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html):

> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).

Your path  is incorrect you need to escape the `\n`:

```
cv2.imread('C:\\Pictures\\naturalScene.bmp',0)
```

Or use `/`:

```
cv2.imread('C:/Pictures/naturalScene.bmp',0)
```

Or as @Martijn Pieters commented use a raw string literal:

```
cv2.imread(r'C:\Pictures\naturalScene.bmp',0)
```

Comment: I figured out that the main issue was the picture. For some reason it pops with the same error even though the path is now correct. Thanks though, if you have not told me I would not have realised that it was initially the wrong path.

Comment: @Pedro, no worries, there must be something wrong with the format of the picture.